# Seams when texture spherical mapping Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture-mapping

I am attempting to map a Texture2D onto a quadsphere. It has successfully wrapped around, apart from the seam where the ends of the textures meet. Can anyone help regarding how to get rid of this seam? I understand that I need to duplicate the vertices on each side, but how would I accomplish this in Unity C#? Below is the code I use to assign my UV's:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 v = mesh.vertices[i];
            Vector2 textureCoordinates;
            textureCoordinates.x = Mathf.Atan2(v.x, v.z) / (-2f * Mathf.PI);
            if (textureCoordinates.x < 0f)
            {
                textureCoordinates.x += 1f;
            }

            textureCoordinates.y = Mathf.Asin(v.y) / Mathf.PI + 0.5f;
            uv[i] = textureCoordinates;
        }
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need two vertices on top of each other **in the mesh vertex data**. If you are actually generating the mesh using code, then you can make sure to generate those vertices in code, but if the mesh comes from Blender or something, then that's where to go to solve the issue.